# Access static readonly fields in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript2.0

I'm new to ionic and I don't know whether I'm doing it right. I've have two buttons UserA, UserB, both buttonsshare same function and I need to pass user-type (UserA, UserB) as parameter when user clicks on a button.

Here's my code:

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from "ionic-angular";
import {BasePage} from "../base/base-page/base-page";
import {Signup} from "../signup/signup";
import {Fields} from "../../enums/fields/Fields";
import {EnumOthers} from "../../enums/EnumOthers";


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector   : 'page-signup-user-type',
  templateUrl: 'signup-user-type.html',
})


export class SignupUserType
{
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams)
  {
  }

  public switchToSignup(userType: number):void
  {
    switch(userType)
    {
      case EnumOthers.USER_A:
      {
        this.navCtrl.push(PageA);
        break;
      }

      case EnumOthers.USER_B:
      {
        this.navCtrl.push(PageB);
        break;
      }

      default:
      {
        console.log("Its not working !!!");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>User Type</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" block (click)="switchToSignup(EnumOthers.USER_A)">A User</button>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" block  (click)="switchToSignup(EnumOthers.USER_B)">B User</button>
</ion-content>
```

I'm trying to pass those parameters as **public static readonly** which are not accessible in my html(Ionic). I don't want to pass hard-coded parameters.

```js
export class EnumOthers
{
  public static readonly USER_A: number = 0;
  public static readonly USER_B: number = 1;
}
```

Code runs successfully, but when I click the button, I get the error. [Here's the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUIbR.png)

Comment: What does your page component look like? Not enough info here to troubleshoot.

Comment: @MikeLunn, I've posted the whole code. Hope it helps

Comment: Try adding a public property to your SignupUserType class and set it with the data in EnumOthers. Without this property you will not be able to access it in the template.

Comment: Thanks @MikeLunn for this method i did the same but with little modifications. I changed EnumOthers to a singelton class, put it in a base class. This way i can access them in my whole app without ending up creating fields in every class.